# entity framework looking in different table during unittests

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have a single DbContext in a library along with entities and their configuration in fluent api.

I use this same context in two different projects.
The first one is a test project and the second one a simple console application.

I execute a query including some of it's relations like this:

```cs
var vacancies = (from v in ctx.Vacancies
                              .Include("Categories")
                              .Include("Levels")
                              .Include("Contracts")
                              .Include("JobTypes"));
```

Strangely enough the console application works perfectly, however the unittest starts looking in the wrong tables all of a sudden.

Both applications produce very different queries when i look at them.

I'm using EF5 atm and I've been stuck on this for a few days now with not a single clue to what might cause this problem.

EDIT:
The point is i don't do any different queries, i also only have on context and only one connectionstring which i have confirmed during runtime connects to the right database.

All i can say is that i feel like the fluent api has no effect in unittests even though it hits the code just fine like it should.

```
 public class SchedulerContext : BaseContext<SchedulerContext>{


    public DbSet<Click> Clicks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ContractType> Contracts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JobType> JobTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Level> Levels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ExternalMapping> ExternalMappings { get; set; }     
    public DbSet<GeoName> GeoNames { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GeoAlternateName> GeoAlternateNames { get; set; }     
    public DbSet<Trigger> JobTriggers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RegistryValue> RegistryValues { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JobResult> JobResults { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JobInfo> JobInfo { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JobError> JobErrors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JobNotification> JobNotifications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Vacancy> Vacancies { get; set; }

    public SchedulerContext() {
        //this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        //this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new VacancyEntityTypeConfiguration());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

That is my context.

And my entity configuration:

```
public class VacancyEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Vacancy> {

    public VacancyEntityTypeConfiguration() {
        this.HasMany(c => c.Levels).
       WithMany().
       Map(
        m => {
            m.ToTable("VacancyLevels");
        });

        this.HasMany(c => c.Categories).
          WithMany().
          Map(
           m => {
               m.ToTable("VacancyCategories");
           });

        this.HasMany(c => c.Contracts).
          WithMany().
          Map(
           m => {
               m.ToTable("VacancyContractTypes");
           });

        this.HasMany(c => c.Jobtypes).
          WithMany().
          Map(
           m => {
               m.ToTable("VacancyJobTypes");
           });
    }
}
```

And the exact method which shows the problem.

```
 public List<Vacancy> GetVacanciesForCustomer(Company customer, bool onlineInclusive) {
        using (var ctx = new JHSchedulerContext.SchedulerContext()) {
            var vacancies = (from v in ctx.Vacancies.Include("Categories").Include("Levels").Include("Contracts").Include("JobTypes") where v.SourceSite == customer.SourceSite && (v.Online || onlineInclusive == false) select v).ToList();
            return vacancies.ToList();
        }
    }
```

And the Vacancy class:

```
 public class Vacancy {

    public Vacancy()
    {
        this.Language = "";
    }

    [SolrUniqueKey("id")]
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length 50 characters")]
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }

    [SolrField("title")]
    [StringLength(1024, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length 1024 characters")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [SolrField("company")]
    [StringLength(1024, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length 1024 characters")]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    [StringLength(4096, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length 4096 characters")]
    public string CompanyText { get; set; }

    [SolrField("location")]
    [StringLength(1024, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length 1024 characters")]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [SolrField("url")]
    [StringLength(1024, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length 1024 characters")]
    public string Url { get; set;}

    [SolrField("source")]
    [StringLength(1024, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length 1024 characters")]
    public string SourceSite { get; set; }

    private string text;
    [SolrField("text")]
    [StringLength(4096, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length 4096 characters")]
    public string Text {
        get {
            return StringHelper.TruncateAtWord(text, 500);
            //return new String(text.Take(500).ToArray());
            //return text.Substring(text.Length < 900 ? 0 : (text.Length / 2), (int)Math.Min(text.Length, 500));
        }
        set{
            text = value;
        }
    }

    [StringLength(4096, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length 4096 characters")]
    public string TextProfile { get; set; }

    [StringLength(4096, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length 4096 characters")]
    public string TextOffer { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public SqlGeography Coordinate {
        get
        {
            if (Latitude.HasValue && Longitude.HasValue)
                return SqlGeography.Point(Latitude.Value, Longitude.Value, 4326);
            else
                return null;
        }
    }

    [SolrField("coordinate_0_coordinate")]
    public double? Latitude { get; set; }

    [SolrField("coordinate_1_coordinate")]
    public double? Longitude { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1024, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length 1024 characters")]
    public string NormalizedLocation { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ScrapedDate { get; set; }

    [SolrField("insertdate")]
    public DateTime? ImportDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ExpireDate { get; set; }     

    [NotMapped]
    public string DaysAgo {
        get {
            if (ImportDate != null)
                return (DateTime.Now - (DateTime)ImportDate).Days.ToString();
            else {
                return "N/A";
            }
        }
    }

    [SolrField("category")]
    public ICollection<string> CategoryNames {
        get { return Categories != null ? Categories.Select(c => c.Name).ToList() : null; }
    }

    [SolrField("level")]
    public ICollection<string> LevelNames {
        get { return Levels != null ? Levels.Select(l => l.Name).ToList() : null; }
    }

    [SolrField("contract")]
    public ICollection<string> ContractNames {
        get { return Contracts != null ? Contracts.Select(c => c.Name).ToList() : null; }
    }

    [SolrField("time")]
    public ICollection<string> JobTypeNames {
        get { return Jobtypes != null ? Jobtypes.Select(c => c.Name).ToList() : null; }
    }

    public string ContactName { get; set; }       

    [Required]
    public bool Online { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int? Distance { get; set; }

    public string Language { get; set; }

    public string PriorityType { get; set; }

    public int NumClicks { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string GridContactName {
        get{
            return string.Format("{0} (Total Clicks:{1})",ContactName,NumClicks);
        }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Level> Levels { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContractType> Contracts { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<JobType> Jobtypes { get; set; }     

    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("Id={0} ExternalId={1} Title={2} Company={3} Location={4} Url={5} SourceSite={6} Text={7} NormalizedLocation={8} InsertDate={9} ImportDate={10} DaysAgo={11}",Id, ExternalId,Title,Company,Location,Url, SourceSite,Text,NormalizedLocation,ScrapedDate,ImportDate,DaysAgo);
    }

}
```

And the Level class(all the other relation classes have the same structure(name,id):

```
   public class Level {

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length 100 characters")]
    public string Name { get; set; }      

    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("Id={0} Name={1}", Id, Name);
    }

}
```

As far as connection to database goes you'll just have to believe me that i've checked both are connecting to the same database.(I even generated a new database with migrations enabled on this one since we use another context for migrations. That still had the exact same issue).

To clarify:
The unittest looks for table: CategoryVacancies.
The console application or even my windows service i use this in look for the right table: VacancyCategories.

Comment: Could you show an example of different queries with the same linq? For us it's even harder to have any clue without more context.

Comment: If unit tests are looking into different tables you most probably have problem with connection string.

Comment: Connectionstring is ok, i've confirmed both application and unittest connect to the same database.

Comment: Does this inversion of names also happen with other junction tables? It looks like the unit test does not execute the `OnModelCreating` creating overload and falls back to default naming convention. Can you confirm that by setting a breakpoint? BTW what is `BaseContext`?

Comment: Tried confirming it's executing with a breakpoint and yes the breakpoint gets hit. Bascontext just enforces a certain connectionstring in it's constructor so every context derived from it uses the same connectionstring. Yes it happens to every single junction table of which we tell EF5 which name it should have instead of letting it base it on conventions. BTW If you need any more info Gert maybe mail might be easier since i see we're both dutch. We can post the solution on here if we find it.